# Qt pushbuttons are not shown when running script

Tags: qt

The interface is shown completely in Qt, but all the buttons are not shown when running the python script.

in Qt: 
[image]

in script:
[image]

Searched online, didn't find a similar issue.
Thanks in advance if anyone can help me on that!

**Additional info**

**The python script:**

```
    class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        uic.loadUi("edytor.ui", self)

        self.layout = []
        self.rgb_layout = []

    self.loadlayout.clicked.connect(self.getfile)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def run_app():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        mapp = Main()

        mapp.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    run_app()
```

**The script for "edytor.ui":**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>notepad</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="notepad">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>659</width>
    <height>191</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Scan</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="loadlayout">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>50</x>
     <y>90</y>
     <width>141</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>-1</pointsize>
     <weight>50</weight>
     <italic>false</italic>
     <bold>false</bold>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background: white;
border-style: outset;
border-width: 0.5px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-color: gray;
font: 14px;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Load Layout Image</string>
   </property>
   <property name="checkable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="autoDefault">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="default">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="flat">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
  </widget> 
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

The python code doesn't show error.

Comment: I only know C++ Qt. Do you use .ui file or qml? Any error printed? Maybe the ui/qml file is not found? "Component is not ready" would be printed in case of qml for example.

Comment: The images don't tell much. Couldn't you post any code?

Comment: Make sure to add the buttons to a layout.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld what do you mean by this? I added the button in the layout. The issue is that the script ran well previously, and it doesn't work recently.